# How to get number of Items scraped by Python Scrapy tool?

Tags: python, scrapy

I am using Python Scrapy tool to extract Data from website. I am able to scrape the Data. Now I want the count of Items scraped from a particular Website. How can I get the Number of items scraped? Is there some built in class for that in Scrapy? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks..

Comment: why not just keep a counter in the final print statement.

Comment: You might wanna have a look at [Scrapy Stats Collection](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/stats.html)

Comment: @pault. I had a look at Scrapy Stats Collection but not able to get the Number of Items Scraped..Should I try something like this http://mahmoud.abdel-fattah.net/2012/07/23/scrapy-extension-to-store-spider-statistics-to-postgesql-db/ ?

Comment: Guys.. I tried the Sample Extension form this link: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/extensions.html.. But how do I set the value of MYEXT_ITEMCOUNT in my settings file... By default I have set it as 1000.. But that doesnt work as I dont get the right answer.. Please help..

Answer (score 3):

Based on the example [here](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/webservice.html#examples-of-web-service-resources), I solved the same problem like this:

1.write a custom web service like this to count the item downloaded:

```
from scrapy.webservice import JsonResource
from scrapy import signals
from scrapy.xlib.pydispatch import dispatcher


class ItemCountResource(JsonResource):

    ws_name = 'item_count'

    def __init__(self, crawler, spider_name=None):
        JsonResource.__init__(self, crawler)
        self.item_scraped_count = 0
        dispatcher.connect(self.scraped, signals.item_scraped)
        self._spider_name = spider_name
        self.isLeaf = spider_name is not None

    def scraped(self):
        self.item_scraped_count += 1

    def render_GET(self, txrequest):
        return self.item_scraped_count

    def getChild(self, name, txrequest):
        return ItemCountResource(name, self.crawler)
```

2.register the service in `settings.py` like this:

```
WEBSERVICE_RESOURCES = {
    'path.to.ItemResource.ItemCountResource': 1,
}
```

3.visite `http://localhost:6080/item_count` will get the item crawled.